# creating docker container to host website

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I want to run static website inside a docker container.
For this i have create ubuntu EC2 machine,installed docker and pulled centos image.

```
docker pull centos
docker run -td 9f38484d220f bash
docker exec -it aa779e39eb0f bash
===>now inside the container i am using below command
    yum update
    yum install apache
    service httpd start
```

but i am getting command not recognized error.

Please help me figure out what i am doing wrong.

Also i as i want to run static website i will be putting below code once apache is installed successfully

```
     $touch /var/www/html/index.html
     $chkconfig httpd on                 
     $echo "<b>Hii this is my first conatiner running/b>" 
      >> /var/www/html/index.html
```

Is this correct way of doing it ?

Comment: what's this id `aa779e39eb0f`, is it the container id or image id? Why dont you try `yum install httpd mod_ssl` instead of `yum install apache`

Comment: When you `docker rm` the container you’ll lose everything.  If you just have a bunch of static files, you don’t need to “run” anything and a container isn’t a great match; consider hosting them somewhere like S3 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installed *apache* and you are trying to run *httpd*. Refer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248404/is-there-any-difference-between-apache2-and-httpd) to read the difference between apache2 and httpd. You can run following commands to install apache and run a static hello world page on local host.

```
$ sudo yum update -y
$ sudo yum install -y httpd
$ sudo service httpd start
$ echo "<html><h1>Hello World!</h1></html>" > test
$ cat test > /var/www/html/index.html
```

Comment: Hi ...i am doing this for learning purpose.i know about the S3 option.              
@bot Thanks ... your solution worked.But for service httpd start "bash: service: command not found".Also if i want to access this website from broswser how it can be done ?

Comment: Are you getting error for *httpd* or *service*? I would try two things (A) run this command as sudo user or (B) run `sudo systemctl start httpd`. After running the commands I mentioned you should be able to see it in the browser. If you add an inbound rule in security group to accept all traffic from 0.0.0.0, you can hit the public DNS of the instance and 'hello world' page will be returned.

Comment: Refer this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/774291/centos-6-5-bash-service-command-not-found) to check to fix `bash: service: command not found` error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a container for hosting a static website. S3 is a better choice for this.

If you want to do it as an exercice, considere this simple nginx solution, see: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx

You have an example in the section : Hosting some simple static content

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Remember that you usually don't start a container then start a service inside (for testing and debugging). Entrypoint and command are what start your service, aka what you would manually do.